# Airflow Executing Operator Twice in Log: Execution Dates Different

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

We are all relatively new here at Airflow so this issue has kind of confused all of us. Within this particular DAG our Engineer has set the DAG to back-fill. Passing the context in ETC etc. What we are currently seeing is two operators within the LOG with very different execution dates (please see below). Please also note that I've shortened the logs so I'm not just pasting everything in.

I also wanted to include the DAG as well as it exists within our Airflow instance. Everything looks correct, and it mirrors what we have done in the past.

Code review on both the DAG, and also the script which is being used to retrieve data from Google. All looks fine to me. I'm rather novice when it comes to these things so I might be missing something here.

LOG for the Script

```
*** Reading local file: /usr/local/airflow/logs/kroger/create_log_dir/2018-03-04T07:00:00+00:00/1.log
[2019-03-29 20:37:26,562] {{models.py:1359}} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: kroger.create_log_dir 2018-03-04T07:00:00+00:00 [queued]>
[2019-03-29 20:37:26,566] {{models.py:1359}} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: kroger.create_log_dir 2018-03-04T07:00:00+00:00 [queued]>
[2019-03-29 20:37:26,566] {{models.py:1571}} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Starting attempt 1 of 4
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[2019-03-29 20:37:26,577] {{models.py:1593}} INFO - Executing <Task(PythonOperator): create_log_dir> on 2018-03-04T07:00:00+00:00

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Starting attempt 1 of 4
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[2019-04-09 01:04:21,054] {{models.py:1593}} INFO - Executing <Task(PythonOperator): create_log_dir> on 2018-03-04T07:00:00+00:00
[2019-04-09 01:04:21,054] {{base_task_runner.py:118}} INFO - Running: 
[2019-04-09 01:04:26,031] {{logging_mixin.py:95}} INFO - [2019-04-09 01:04:26,030] {{jobs.py:2527}} INFO - Task exited with return code 0
```

DAG as it currently stands

```
args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2018, 1, 1),
    # 'email': [''],
    # 'email_on_failure': True,
    # 'email_on_retry': False,
     'retries': 3,
     'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=15),
    # 'schedule_interval':'0 10 * * *',
    # 'queue': 'bash_queue',
    # 'pool': 'backfill',
    # 'priority_weight': 10,
    # 'end_date': datetime(2019, 4, 12),
}


dag = DAG(dag_id='kroger',
          default_args=args,
          schedule_interval="0 7 * * *",
          catchup=True)

t0 = PythonOperator(task_id='create_log_dir',
                    python_callable=utils.create_account_dirs,
                    op_args=['kroger'],
                    dag=dag)
                    # on_failure_callback=send_notification)

t1 = PythonOperator(task_id = 'build_ds_table',
                    python_callable=build_schema.create_schema,
                    provide_context=True,
                    dag=dag)
                    # on_failure_callback=send_notification)

t2 =  PythonOperator(task_id = 'ds',
                     python_callable= ds.upload_ds_report,
                     provide_context=True,
                     dag=dag)

t0 >> t1
t1 >> t2
```

Right now it all appears to be working as expected in regards to the data we are retrieving. I just was reviewing the LOGS and the multiple operators per log kind of worried me. Please let me know if there is any more information I could provide here to make this question better for y'all.